# Capture Popup page content through CasperJS or PhantomJS

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

A.html

```
<input type="submit" name="testLabel" value="Print Test" id="testLabel" onclick="myFunction('<?php echo $dynamic_page;?>')" >

<script>
function myFunction(page) {
    var strWindowFeatures = "location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";
    window.open(page, "_blank",strWindowFeatures);
}
</script>
```

CasperJS code

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://localhost/test/a.html', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.thenClick('#testLabel');

casper.then(function() {
    this.capture('page.png');
});

casper.run();
```

I have also try with phantomjs but i am not able to capture b.html page in page.png

Note : Popup page name is not fixed.

Comment: But in real problem popup screen is blank popup is taking time in loading content how can resolve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// this will set the popup DOM as the main active one only for time the

// step closure being executed

```
casper.withPopup(0, function() {
    this.test.assertTitle('Popup title');
});
```

Complete code

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://localhost/test/a.html', function () {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.thenClick('#testLabel');

casper.waitForPopup(0, function () {
    this.echo('Popup');
});

casper.then(function () {
    this.capture('page.png');
});

casper.run();
```

Read more about [waitForPopup](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitForPopup)

Answer (score 1):

There is [waitForPopup](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforpopup) and [withPopup](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#withpopup) methods so your code would look like this

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://localhost/test/a.html', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.thenClick('#testLabel');

casper.waitForPopup(/.\.html$/, function() {
    this.echo('Popup')
});

casper.withPopup(0, function() {
    this.capture('page.png');
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: This is not working because we can't write direct value b.html in waitForPopup this related amazon sellercentral scraping

Comment: So don't write direct value `b.html`. If you can see that is a regex so you could catch whatever value you want dynamically.

Comment: Incorrect answer can you complete With regex i have search on google then ask because your answer is all-ready on stack-overflow

Comment: This answer answers your question exactly. You can either provide the real example and the real code or rework my code so it suits you. Saying it is incorrect is just false

Comment: If you have idea about amazon cellercentral this related to print invoice and label where when you click on print then open content in pdf i have no idea who have up vote you

Comment: I don't have an idea, that's why I asked you to post real problem, with example. Whoever voted up recognized this as an answer, which it is. Your new question is related to regexp, which has nothing to do with casperjs anymore. My code clearly takes screenshot of popup that was invoked from casper, just what the question asks.

Comment: Mario Thank you very much your answer is working perfetct